# when connecting to an ec2 via SSH, how to transfer files?

Tags: ftp, amazon-ec2

I connect to an ec2 instance via SSH.

What options do I have to transfer files over to my linux box?

Is there anything other than setting up an FTP server?

(I'm on a windows computer )

Answer (score 6):

Download WinSCP and use the sftp functionality. It makes use of your ssh connection.

Answer (score 4):

Use scp with the same arguments as ssh:

```
scp -i key.pem path/to/local/file user@aws-server:path/to/remote/file
```

Answer (score 2):

An ec2 instance is the same as any other server, so you don't need to think in regards to how to work with ec2, just how to work with a linux server.

I prefer using [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) as it supports multiple types including FTP and SFTP so I can have all of my sites saved in one client.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it on Ubuntu:

```
sshfs ubuntu@1.2.3.4:/ /home/matt/EC2 -o ssh_command='ssh -i /home/matt/.ssh/key.pem'
```